# Quantum Wonderland? 

Tags: worldbuilding-process

I want to create a world that demonstrates the basic ideas of quantum physics but also gives off 'Alice in Wonderland' vibes.

I want there to be a law in Quantum Wonderland that goes something along the lines of:
"Whatever you perceive to be real is your reality" sort of thing. It's like a philosophical take on superposition and entanglement? Kind of? Not really? But I like to pretend it does?

That way, as my characters go mad, they can have supernatural powers like all good isekai protags :)

The issue with this is that I don't exactly understand how it would work out in practice? Like it would be too OP if I could be like: "I am cray cray and, to me, my enemy looks dead so they are! Yay!"

Any ideas on what a good idea to implement this sort of law would be? I know this is a pretty vague but I would appreciate any and all ideas.

I've thought about this a lot and I'm super stuck so all ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Wasn't there a [famous series of films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix) based on the idea that *"whatever you perceive to be real is your reality"?* Somehow, they stretched it successfully to three (soon to be four) films, so that is appears that in the hands of a skillful storyteller it's not at all OP. (And, let's not forget, welcome to Worldbuilding! You may want to take the [tour] and spend some time with the [help] to understand how this site works, and what are its goals and expectations.)

Comment: Have you worked out a proto-mechanic for how the characters thoughts get turned into reality? Most stories I've read that deal with thought-effecting-reality deal with this by having the character enter a different level of reality abstraction; you start dealing with the 'concept' of a thing rather then the 'physical reality' of it.

Comment: @AlexP Soon to be four?

Comment: Hello Sabri. I apologize for voting to close the question, but we need a chance to help you focus your thoughts and goals. This question quite literally invites us to build your world for you and that's outside the scope of the site. It appears you've started a journey (to build your world) without understanding the boat you'll be sailing on (quantum mechanics). If that's true, helping you understand QM is well outside our purview. Could you [read this first](https://www.quantamagazine.org/entanglement-made-simple-20160428/)? I think the "many worlds" aspect might help.

Comment: @TheDaleks: [*The Matrix 4*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_4).

Comment: - [Forbidden Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)  
- [Dark City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_City_(1998_film))
- [What Dreams May Come](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Dreams_May_Come_(film))

Comment: While I did have to vote to close as this is too open ended, one particularly useful tool would be the Many Worlds Interpretation, where facts are only true or false with respect to a specific subject who is observing them.  This would lead to interesting philosophical patterns that MWI has to deal with, such as quantum suicide.  You may be able to observe anything you want, but it results in you seeing a vanishingly small portion of the world.

Comment: It lends itself to questions of "what is a 'self' anyways?"  And, of course, when there is no classical self to observe with, one is open to the entire quantum waveform.

Comment: Tastes like solipsism, as a law of physics?